# Phoenix udf not working

Tags: hbase, udf, apache-phoenix

I am trying to run a custom udf in apache phoenix but getting error. Please help me to figure out the issue.

**Following is my function class:**

```
package co.abc.phoenix.customudfs;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.phoenix.expression.Expression;
import org.apache.phoenix.expression.function.ScalarFunction;
import org.apache.phoenix.parse.FunctionParseNode.Argument;
import org.apache.phoenix.parse.FunctionParseNode.BuiltInFunction;
import org.apache.phoenix.schema.tuple.Tuple;
import org.apache.phoenix.schema.types.PDataType;
import org.apache.phoenix.schema.types.PVarchar;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.lang.Long.parseLong;
import static org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern;

@BuiltInFunction(name = EpochToDateFunction.NAME, args = {
  @Argument(allowedTypes = {PVarchar.class}), @Argument(allowedTypes = {PVarchar.class})})
public class EpochToDateFunction extends ScalarFunction {

  public static final String NAME = "EpochToDate";
  private static final Map<String, DateTimeFormatter> DATE_FORMATTERS = new HashMap<>();

  public String getName() {
    return NAME;
  }

  public boolean evaluate(Tuple tuple, ImmutableBytesWritable ptr) {
    Expression arg = getChildren().get(0);
    if (!arg.evaluate(tuple, ptr)) return false;
    String epochStr = new String(ptr.copyBytes());
    arg = getChildren().get(1);
    if (!arg.evaluate(tuple, ptr)) return false;
    String dfStr = new String(ptr.copyBytes());
    if (!DATE_FORMATTERS.containsKey(dfStr)) DATE_FORMATTERS.put(dfStr, forPattern(dfStr));
    String dateStr = DATE_FORMATTERS.get(dfStr).print(parseLong(epochStr));
    ptr.set(PVarchar.INSTANCE.toBytes(dateStr));
    return true;
  }

  public PDataType getDataType() {
    return PVarchar.INSTANCE;
  }

}
```

**Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1-HBase-1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**hbase-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
     <name>phoenix.functions.allowUserDefinedFunctions</name>
     <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
          <name>hbase.dynamic.jars.dir</name>
            <value>${hbase.rootdir}/lib</value>
        </property>
        <property>
              <name>hbase.local.dir</name>
                <value>${hbase.tmp.dir}/local/</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

**I added the custom jar in hbase.dynamic.jars.dir**

```
$ ./bin/hadoop fs -ls /hbase/lib/
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 nj supergroup   79798208 2017-03-16 10:08 /hbase/lib/phoenix-custom-udfs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Create and execute function**

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> CREATE FUNCTION EpochToDate(varchar, varchar) returns varchar as 'co.abc.phoenix.customudfs.EpochToDateFunction' using jar 'hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase/lib/phoenix-custom-udfs-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar';
No rows affected (0.018 seconds)

0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> select epochtodate('1489637458000', 'yyyy');
Error: ERROR 6001 (42F01): Function undefined. functionName=EPOCHTODATE (state=42F01,code=6001)
org.apache.phoenix.schema.FunctionNotFoundException: ERROR 6001 (42F01): Function undefined. functionName=EPOCHTODATE
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.FromCompiler$1.resolveFunction(FromCompiler.java:129)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ExpressionCompiler.visitLeave(ExpressionCompiler.java:313)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ProjectionCompiler$SelectClauseVisitor.visitLeave(ProjectionCompiler.java:688)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ProjectionCompiler$SelectClauseVisitor.visitLeave(ProjectionCompiler.java:584)
    at org.apache.phoenix.parse.FunctionParseNode.accept(FunctionParseNode.java:86)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.ProjectionCompiler.compile(ProjectionCompiler.java:416)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSingleFlatQuery(QueryCompiler.java:561)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSingleQuery(QueryCompiler.java:507)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compileSelect(QueryCompiler.java:202)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.QueryCompiler.compile(QueryCompiler.java:157)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:406)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:380)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:271)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:266)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:265)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1446)
    at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
    at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:807)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost>
```

Can someone help me and let me know where am I missing any configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem in the past.

Basically you need to select some row from a table for UDF's to work (provided that you've written the rest of your UDF properly)

so something like

select udffunc(1,1) won't work

but

select udffunc(col1, 1) from table will

http://eyang3.github.io/2016/12/13/post/

Comment: Hey Eric, can you help me with this: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/91946/running-phoenix-udfs-from-java-service.html ?

Comment: Are you connecting to the same cluster?

I'm looking at the following error message:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.<name>.phoenix.customudfs.EpochPastDays

the <name> looks suspicious...

Comment: @AbhishekKumar
We copied the jar to the path mentioned in this property in the hbase-site.xml file in phoenix client
`<property>
  <name>hbase.dynamic.jars.dir</name>
  <value>${hbase.rootdir}/lib</value>
</property>`

actual path in mapr-fs (hdfs) : "/hbase/lib"

While creating the function we didn't mention jar path.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
        url: sourceDatabaseConfiguration.url,
        drivername: sourceDatabaseConfiguration.driverName,
        maxpoolsize: sourceDatabaseConfiguration.maxpoolsize,
        properties: {
            'phoenix.functions.allowUserDefinedFunctions': 'true',
            'phoenix.query.timeoutMs': '1800000',
            'hbase.regionserver.lease.period': '1200000',
            'hbase.rpc.timeout': '1200000',
            'hbase.client.scanner.caching': '1000',
            'hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period': '1200000'

        }
```

That's my JDBC connection object that I use for UDF's